# Looping issues? jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, asp-classic

I have a dynamic table which has three textboxes and a select dropdown in each row that is added. On the click of a button, more rows can be added dynamically. Once I click submit I want to the loop through each cell but in the tbody section ONLY; when trying the loop is just skipped over. I have already tried debugging in console but no issues were found.

Here is my HTML:

```
<table id= "tb1" class="norm sideBG" name="recordTable" align="center" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0" border="1" bordercolor="lightgrey" width="600px">
  <tr class="norm">
    <td>
      <b><u>LMV PART #</u></b>
    </td>
    <td>
      <b><u>LOCATION</u></b>
    </td>
    <td>
      <b><u>QUANTITY</u></b>
    </td>
    <td>
      <b><u>WHERE USED</u></b>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tbody class="theRow" id="theRow">
    <tr>
      <td class="norm">
        <label id="partLabel" style="color : red;"></label>
        <br />
        <input type='text' name='txtbox0[]' id='txtbox0[]' onchange="javascript: changeLabel(this)" />
      </td>
      <td class="norm">
        <select id="txtbox1[]" name="txtbox1[]" >
          <%
             strSQL1 = "myQuery"
             Set oRs1 = oConn1.Execute(strSQL1)
             Do while not oRs1.eof
             Response.Write("<OPTION VALUE='" & Mid(oRs1(0),4) & "'")
             Response.Write(">" & Mid(oRs1(0),4) & "</OPTION>")
             oRs1.movenext
             loop
             oRs1.Close
             oConn1.Close
             %>
            </select>
          </td>
      <td class="norm">
        <input type='text' name='txtbox2[]' id='txtbox2[]' />
      </td>
      <td class="norm">
        <input type='text' name='txtbox3[]' id='txtbox3[]' />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Along with my jQuery loop which is processed on submit()

```
var cellVal;
$("#tb1 > tbody.theRow > tr").each(function() {
  cellVal = $(this).text();
  if (cellVal.length == 0 || cellVal == null)
  {
    alert("there's a blank field");
    blankFields = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: You want to get the values of `textbox` and `select`?

Comment: There's only one `<tr>` so you get only once!

Comment: Yes every value, from the textboxes and select dropdown in each row @Tushar

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have a script that dynamically adds another row each time a button is clicked so there can be an infinite amount of rows. The script copies the tbody I already have in my code.

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML output?

Answer (score 1):

Use `each` on `td` instead of `tr`:

```
var cellVal;
$("#theRow tr td").each(function () {

    // If td contain textbox
    if ($(this).find('input').length) {
        cellVal = $.trim($(this).val());
        // Get value of textbox
    } else if ($(this).find('select').length) {
        // If contains drop-down get the selected option value
        cellVal = $(this).find('select option:selected').val();
    }

    if (!cellVal.length) {
        alert("there's a blank field");
        blankFields = true;
    }
});
```

Also, you don't need `[]` in the names of textbox and drop-downs.

Comment: Thanks @Tushar, I'm now getting this error from the console for the first IF statement?: 'Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: textbox'